# Need an Input Validation in a Java program(Java 2 SE)

Tags: java, input

I had made a java program in which it is supposed to take input from a user in a GUI frame and store in a .dat file in row and columns. The problem is with this particular code as it is not giving the desired results. the user should be able to enter only numbers between 20 to 30 using a keylistener. the input should not accept any number that is out of this range, i.e, 19 or 31. Eclipse is throwing an error 'invalid character constant'. Is there any way out?

```
// input validation that restricts user to enter specific number range between 20 and 30

txDeposit.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
        char c = ke.getKeyChar();
        if(!(ke.getKeyChar() >= '20' && ke.getKeyChar() <= '30')) {
            getToolkit().beep();
            ke.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: A character in Java is a single letter (so to speak), so '20', '30', etc. won't work

Comment: Can you use a [slider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) control instead?

Comment: You can try method like .getText() at submit even.You can do something like Integer.pasrseInt(txDeposit.getText()) then compare this value with 20 and 30.

Answer (score 0):

`KeyListener`s are unreliable in this situation as you have no guarantee in what order the listeners are handled in.  It's possible that the field has already processed the key event before you...

Instead, you should be using [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html)

Check [here](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for examples

A simpler solution would be just to use a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

### Document Filter Example

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class TestNumericFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestNumericFilter();
    }

    public TestNumericFilter() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JTextField field = new JTextField(3);
            ((AbstractDocument) field.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new IntFilter());
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(field);
        }
    }

    public class IntFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                String text, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {

            boolean valid = true;
            for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    valid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (valid) {

                int incoming = Integer.parseInt(text);
                int length = fb.getDocument().getLength();
                if (length == 0 && text.length() == 1) {
                    if (incoming >= 2 && incoming <= 3) {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
                    } else {
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    }
                } else {
                    String value = fb.getDocument().getText(0, length) + text;
                    incoming = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    if (incoming >= 20 && incoming <= 30) {
                        super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
                    } else {
                        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (length > 0) {
                fb.remove(offset, length);
            }
            insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot be compiled because ``` `` is used to mark characters, not string. Character constant consist of one and only one character only. Therefore ```'20'` is invalid.

Now, as far as I understand you want to capture *numbers* from 20 to 30. 2 digit number consists of 2 digits and therefore you have to make your validation more sophisticated: if first character is `2` you have to wait for characters from 0 to 9, if first character is `'3'` only `'0'` is allowed.

Once 2 characters are entered you have to reset the state and wait for '2' or '3' again.

I just doubt you really want to do this.
As far as I understand you added listener to text field, didn't you? In this case do not check the currently entered character. Check content of the text field:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(tx.getText());
if (number < 20 || number > 30) {
    getToolkit().beep();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pre-made java component that extends JTextField. It provides length limitation and regular expression checks. You can easily just use that component and add a regex to limit the number.

You can optionally, and easily, edit the code (specifically the insertString() method) and add your own custom checking.

You can check out a blog post about it here https://subversivebytes.wordpress.com/2012/10/09/java-create-custom-regex-jtextfield/ and the code is complete and free to copy/paste

It's just one of those "why reinvent the wheel" things...